# Python ascii tuple

Tags: python, string, ascii, tuples

I need to communicate with a module accepting uint8_t tuple input in Python.
Say there is an string:

```
str="9,2,..."
```

Is there a function that can turn the string to a tuple like:

```
encoded_tuple=(57,44,50,...)
```

The tuple includes the uint8_t decimal values corresponding to (`0x39,0x2c,0x32,...`) which are the ASCII values of the characters in the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`ord`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) functions.

```
>>> mystr = '9,2,...'
>>> tuple(map(ord, mystr))
(57, 44, 50, 44, 46, 46, 46)
```

The `ord` function returns the unicode value of a single character. The `map` function applies `ord` to every character in the string, leaving you with the tuple.

Also, take care not to use `str` as a variable name, as it will overwrite the built in function.